# on_voice_state_update() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Hi I'm getting the error `on_voice_state_update() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given` but I'm unsure whats causing this error. I have tried a few other menthods which keeps on producing the same Type error.

This is the code I'm working work

**Update:**

```
from discord.ext import commands
import random
from random import randint
import discord
import asyncio

class vtcmention:
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    async def on_voice_state_update(self, before, after, member: discord.Member):
        log_channel = self.bot.get_channel(CHANNEL_ID)
        vc_before = before.voice_channel
        vc_after = after.voice_channel
        CHANNEL_ID = '481478695794638859'

        if vc_before == vc_after: return

        if vc_before is None:
            msg = "**{}** joined **{}**".format(member.name, vc_after.name)
        elif vc_after is None:
            msg = "**{}** left **{}**".format(name.name, vc_before.name)
        else:
            msg = "**{}** moved into **{}** from **{}**".format(member.name, vc_before.name, vc_after.name)

        await self.bot.send_message(log_channel, msg)


def setup(bot):
    n = vtcmention(bot)
    bot.add_cog(n)
```

If anyone can help me where I'm going wrong here I'd much appreciate it.
Thank you.

Comment: Please provide the lines that call this function

Comment: I don't understand?

Comment: The function does not appear to be called in the code you posted. Is it being invoked form somewhere else? Also, it's not entirely clear, because of the code formatting, if it is a standalone function of a method of class `vtcmention`.

Comment: I have made some amendments to the code now I bump in to a new error `
TypeError: on_voice_state_update() missing 1 required positional argument: 'member'`

Comment: Is this all of your code? if possible, can you provide the entire error message?

Comment: Please include all of the code. We can't help you without all of it. Make sure to not include your token.